# Understanding how the rules of probability apply to probability density functions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I'm trying to understand how the rules of probability apply with probability density functions. If I denote the two continuous random variables as $X$ and $Y$ and their corresponding joint distribution as $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ are the following derivations legit / true / correctly understood:

$$P(Y = y) = \lim_{\Delta y \rightarrow0} \int_{y}^{y+\Delta y}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

$$P(X = x) = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow0} \int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$

$$P(Y=y, X=x) = \lim_{\Delta y, \Delta x \rightarrow 0}\int_{y}^{y+\Delta y}\int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

$$P(Y=y \;|\;X=x) = \frac{P(Y=y, X=x)}{P(X=x)} = \frac{\lim_{\Delta y, \Delta x \rightarrow 0}\int_{y}^{y+\Delta y}\int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy}{\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow0} \int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy\,dx}$$

The reason I ask this is because I try to understand why the rules of conditional probability (and therefore Bayes' theorem) hold also for density functions:

$$f_{X|Y}(x\mid y) = \frac{f_{Y|X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)}{f_Y(y)}$$

I asked a question related to this at this post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/592606/edit
but I didn't get a satisfying answer yet..

Are my derivations correctly interpreted? Why does conditional probability rule also hold for density function? Or is it because:

[image]

is the same as

$$f_{X|Y}(x\mid y) = \frac{f_{Y|X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)}{f_Y(y)}$$

If we just cancel the $dx$:s and $dy$:s?? Hope everybody gets what I'm trying to ask x) 
In summary: If you look at what I've sketched and wrote, does it seem I've got the point? :) Or is there something I'm missing?

[image]

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: If X and Y are continuous random variables the three displayed quantities are 0 and the fourth is undefined, being 0/0. The formula relating conditional and unconditional densities is correct though.

Comment: +1 @Did thnx for the help :) Ok, yes I understand what you mean. Would you say it is wrong to write the three displayed quantities the way I did? :)

Comment: Unless you want to write $0=0$, yes this is wrong.

Comment: +1 Thnx @Did could you emphasize a bit more on why it is wrong. Could you say that it is correct, but it's just a another way of writing $0 = 0$? :)

Comment: It sems obvious that when writing P(Y=y), for example, what you mean is really the value at y of the density function of Y, in which case one should replace the LHS by f_Y(y) and at least divide the RHS by Δy. What is written, when the density f_Y exists, is just that P(Y=y)=0 is equal to the RHS=0. Note also that you equate "being continuous" with "being densitable", although these conditions are not equivalent hence the limit of the RHS deivided by Δy might not exist, even for continuous random variables Y (hence my first comment should read "densitable" instead of "continuous", mea culpa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X,Y)$ is a densitable couple of random variables, then the three displayed quantities are $0$ and the fourth is undefined, being $0/0$. The formula relating conditional and unconditional densities is correct though.

It sems obvious that when writing $P(Y=y)$, for example, what you mean is really the value at $y$ of the density function of $Y$, in which case one should replace the LHS by $f_Y(y)$ and at least divide the RHS by $Δy$ for the formula to make sense. What is written, when the density $f_Y$ exists, is just that $P(Y=y)=0$ is equal to the RHS, also equal to $0$. Note finally that you equate "being continuous" with "being densitable", although these conditions are not equivalent hence the limit of the RHS deivided by $Δy$ might not exist, even for continuous random variables $Y$.

Comment: +1 Thank you @Did for your answer! =) Have a nice xmas ;)